# Microsoft Word Interop: SaveAs hangs for some misterious argument types

Tags: powershell, ms-word, com

When trying to simplify a PowerShell script that converts from Word to PDF, I found out the following weird scenario that blows my mind.  Here's the transcript from a proof of concept interactive session:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\Frag> Add-Type -AssemblyName Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
PS C:\Users\Frag> $word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
PS C:\Users\Frag> $i = Get-Item ".\document.docx"
PS C:\Users\Frag> $i.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     FileInfo                                 System.IO.FileSystemInfo


PS C:\Users\Frag> $i.FullName
C:\Users\Frag\document.docx
PS C:\Users\Frag> $doc = $word.Documents.Open($i.FullName)
PS C:\Users\Frag> $doc.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    DocumentClass                            System.__ComObject


PS C:\Users\Frag> $good = $i.FullName.Remove($i.FullName.Length - $i.Extension.Length) + ".pdf"
PS C:\Users\Frag> $bad = Join-Path $i.DirectoryName ($i.BaseName + ".pdf")
PS C:\Users\Frag> $good
C:\Users\Frag\document.pdf
PS C:\Users\Frag> $bad
C:\Users\Frag\document.pdf
PS C:\Users\Frag> $good -eq $bad
True
PS C:\Users\Frag> $good.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object


PS C:\Users\Frag> $bad.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object


PS C:\Users\Frag> Remove-Item -LiteralPath $good -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
PS C:\Users\Frag> $doc.SaveAs($good, [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat]::wdFormatPDF)
PS C:\Users\Frag> dir $good


    Directory: C:\Users\Frag


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       11/03/2017     22:50         174616 document.pdf


PS C:\Users\Frag> Remove-Item -LiteralPath $good -Force
PS C:\Users\Frag> $doc.SaveAs($bad, [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat]::wdFormatPDF)
```

The last command hangs, and the shell window has to be closed as well as the invisible Word instance killed from the task manager.

By the looks of it, `$good` and `$bad` appear to be of **different** string types.  Does anyone know what is going on here?

#### Update

I managed to fix the issue by adding an explicit cast:

```
PS C:\Users\Frag> [string]$bad = Join-Path $i.DirectoryName ($i.BaseName + ".pdf")
```

So the issue is gone, but I'd still very much appreciate an explanation or a pointer.

Comment: @wOxxOm positive.  You can try it out, I'm sure you can reproduce it.  I'm under the impression that outputs from cmdlets are wrapped by some sort of magic object that doesn't serialize properly when sent as the argument of a COM message.

Comment: Hmm, I give up. FWIW `$doc.SaveAs([string]$bad, .....)` succeeds (same as your edit).

Comment: This also worked for me. What doesn't make sense is that xls and ppt to xlsx and pptx do not have this problem...

Answer (score 0):

```
    $saveFormat = [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat]::wdFormatDocumentDefault
    $doc.saveas([ref][system.object]$wordFile, [ref]$saveFormat)
```

works for me...