# Word.Application Freezing/Hanging on certain files

Tags: powershell, ms-word

I am trying to create PDF documents from .docx documents in bulk.  For no rhyme or reason (file permissions are the same, the files have no macros, etc.) the file will just hang.  I have to kill the Word process and force-close PowerShell.

The script is here:

```
[CmdletBinding()]

Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$FilePath
)

$Files = Get-ChildItem -Recurse "$FilePath\*.docx"

$Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application

foreach ($File in $Files) {
    # open a Word document, filename from the directory
    $Doc = $Word.Documents.Open($File.FullName)
    Write-Verbose "Test $($File.FullName)"
    # Swap out DOCX with PDF in the Filename
    $Name = ($Doc.FullName).Replace("docx","pdf")

    # Save this File as a PDF in Word 2010/2013
    $Doc.SaveAs([ref] [string]$Name, [ref] 17)
    $Doc.Close()
}
```

Here is the PowerShell output. You can see the file it hangs on:

[image: Powershell Output]

It does this for maybe 2-3% of files.  This looks very similar to this problem posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42741161/microsoft-word-interop-saveas-hangs-for-some-misterious-argument-types). However, their solution does not resolve my issue.

Does anyone have any suggestions?  I'd also like to know if there's an intuitive way to debug this.  I cannot see the program throwing any errors.

Comment: Troubleshooting com objects in general is pretty difficult from PowerShell just due to often-generic exception messages.

Comment: Does it crash on the same file(s) every time, i.e. indicating some internal difference / corruption with the file(s)?

Comment: Yes, the same files every time.  Fundamentally, there is nothing different with the file.  They were created with the same version of word, they're all a similar file-size, no macros, etc.

Answer (score 0):

How about to close the whole application (yes, it's slower), instead of each document? Something like this:

```
Foreach ($File in $Files) {

    $Word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application 

    $Name = $File.FullName -replace ‘docx’,’pdf’

    ($Word.Documents.Open($File.FullName)).SaveAs([ref]$Name,[ref]17)

    $Word.Application.ActiveDocument.Close()

    $Word.Quit()
}
```